# How to avoid infinite loop with One-To-One relationship in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, loops

In my application  we are having some trouble dealing with people with spouse, the problem is that each person may have a spouse, and this spouse will have to have this person. If you think close about it you will notice that this relation creates a infinite loop.

Normally I would resolve this by putting a `@JsonIgnore` at the "spouse" attribute, but I we use this attribute in our requests because we use Json's to create the object.

I would try to use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`, but there's just one class, the class "person", the loop is happening because this class has itself.

Is there other annotation that I'm forgetting? or other way to fix this?

Comment: alternatively, you could make it `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` then in your query, explicitly join and FETCH. `from Person p join FETCH p.spouse`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final String address;

    private Person spouse;
    
    public boolean isMarried() {
        return null != spouse;
    }
}

// test
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Person john = new Person("john", 28, "London", null);
Person gill = new Person("gill", 24, "London", null);
john.setSpouse(gill);
gill.setSpouse(john);
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(john));
```

Output printed:

```
{
  "@id" : 1,
  "name" : "john",
  "age" : 28,
  "address" : "London",
  "spouse" : {
    "@id" : 2,
    "name" : "gill",
    "age" : 24,
    "address" : "London",
    "spouse" : 1,
    "married" : true
  },
  "married" : true
}
```

If you have property `id` defined inside your class, you should use `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")`.